# CVS: command-line diff on a remote CVS server between two HEAD revs

Tags: command-line, cvs

My CVS-fu is not very strong anymore (after years of SVN'ing and now Mercurial'ing). I'm trying to do a diff between two revisions of the HEAD branch (everything is in the HEAD anyway).

I received an IDE already set up to use a `:pserver:myname@cvsserver:port/cvs/project` CVS. I'm on Windows XP.  I do *not* want to use the IDE (the goal here is to learn CVS a bit more).

Apparently I cannot login using SSH to the CVS server.

How can I run a remote CVS diff between two HEAD revs using the command line?

*P.S: I am new here, mod me up so I can comment etc. :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you want to learn more CVS after experiencing the wonders of SVN and Mercurial?  In this industry, the opportunity cost of learning an outdated and difficult-to-use technology is that you forego the opportunity to learn something new and potentially more useful.

You may of course have a good reason, such as company requirements or other things outside of your control :(

With that said, this resource essentially serves as a CVS guidebook and a reference to many CVS command line tools.  It looks like you can see differences between revisions on the HEAD, but only one file at a time.

http://kuparinen.org/martti/comp/cvs/cvs.html#8

```
  [Show changes between two versions]
  # cvs diff -u -r 1.42 -r 1.43 filename
  # cvs diff -u -r BEFORE-XYZ -r HEAD [filename]
```

Comment: yup, company requirements... I could launch these but the issue here is that I can't login to the CVS server.  All I've got is that :pserver:myname@cvserver:port/cvs/project creds.  How can I enter the 'cvs' command you showed if I cannot login to the CVS server?

Comment: Perhaps posting the error message you are receiving would be helpful.  Not being able to login is a broad description :)  And you are correct, if you can't login, be it IDE or command line, you cannot DIFF anything.

Comment: +1 for helping me... No I mean: accessing the CVS using the pserver auth method obviously works fine from the IDE.  What I cannot do is log *using SSH* on the CVS server.  So I don't know where/how to enter the *cvs diff -...* command you showed me.